# ffmpeg stop after 1 or 2 hours with error : Cannot read file : Too many open files

Tags: ffmpeg, reload, drawtext

When I use drawtext with realod=1,  after 1 or 2 hours my ffmpeg stop with error:

```
[Parsed_drawtext_7 @ 0x563aa3230f00] [FILE @ 0x7fff415ec800] Cannot read file 'myfile.txt': 
Too many open files
[Parsed_drawtext_7 @ 0x563aa3230f00] The text file 'myfile.txt' could not be read or is 
empty
Error while filtering: Too many open files
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Too many open files
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #5:0
```

I make a bash file that change the file every 3 minutes but I have the same problem.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

From the [drawtext filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext):

> `reload`
> If set to `1`, the `textfile` will be reloaded before each frame. **Be sure to update it atomically, or it may be read partially, or even fail.**

So the textfile must be updated atomically, such as by using `mv` in Linux or macOS.

Comment: Thanks, but I already make that.  my textfile update every 2 minutes I dont know why I still got this error.

Comment: @timimi You didn't mention that in the question, so I made a reasonable assumption. How are you updating `myfile.txt`?

Comment: Ah sorry.   I make it like this:    echo "this is the text "> myfile.txt.tmp  mv myfile.txt.tmp  myfile.txt

Comment: @timimi Show your bash script and whatever other info is needed to duplicate this issue. What is your ffmpeg version? You can edit your question to include this info.

Comment: I put it in the edi question.

Comment: ffmpeg version N-57631-gebedd26eef-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Cop                                                                                                                                                             yright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)

Comment: @timimi That command can't be right. You're using overlay filter but only have 1 input. Show the actual command.

Comment: ah ok it was a big command i wanted to simplify it

Comment: Did you see where I insert my text file that come was updated every 2 minutes?

Comment: @timimi You've made it too difficult and time consuming to provide help. You should always provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There are many other questions that need answers.

Comment: sorry I put my code in question.   thanks for patience

Answer (score 0):

I found something

I put "ulimit -n 10000"  before I run my ffmpeg command